# How to place a composable in a specific spot inside a box

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently working on a project where I have three composable. The first two are two different sides of the screen and the third composable needs to be placed in between the two sides and on top of them.

This image better represents what I am asking,
[image].

I need to place the red box in between and on top of the other two composable. The problem I am having is the placement. All three composable are inside a box

I tried adding the red box inside the black area column and then offsetting it so that it overlaps the blue area. The problem with this is that the column still measures the red box as if it was still inside the black area column. I don't want that, I want the red box to be independent but it needs to know where the black area ends so that it can place itself relative to it. I'm not sure if Boxwithconstraint will help, I can't find any examples of this problem.

Comment: Is the bottom of the red box always in the middle of the screen ?

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout) for that:

```
ConstraintLayout {
    // Create references for the composables to constrain
    val (topContainer, bottomContainer, middleContainer) = createRefs()

    Spacer(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(200.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Black)
            .constrainAs(topContainer) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
            }
    )
    Spacer(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .constrainAs(bottomContainer) {
                top.linkTo(topContainer.bottom)
            }
    )
    Spacer(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(200.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
            .constrainAs(middleContainer) {
                top.linkTo(topContainer.bottom)
                bottom.linkTo(bottomContainer.top)
            }
    )
}
```

The outcome of the code is exactly as the image you have above.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. Now to further elaborate on the problem. I will also need to put more composable under the red box, Currently I Just set the padding to 100 for the composable to not be blocked by the red box which I don't want to do. Would I do this also using Constraint Layout. Also why not BoxWithConstraint?

Comment: I would create another box underneath the second Spacer and inside that box add the rest of the views. Then you constraint the box: `.constraintAs(contentBox) { top.linkTo(middleContainer.bottom)    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)`.

Comment: Regarding the BoxWithConstraints, good question! The BoxWithConstraints can adjust the layouts depending on the available screen space but AFAIK you can constraint one view to another

Answer (score 0):

```
Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(200.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Black)
        )
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Blue)
        )
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 100.dp).padding(20.dp).height(200.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Red)
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to place the components in those position and not use padding to push it into it because the sizes may change and I want a consistent look. What you did is what i currently have and I'm am looking for a different solution. It seems a constraint layout may be the solution. Thank You for taking the time to reply.